# SVN Views don't work for Subclipse and Eclipse 4.6 (neon)

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, eclipse-neon

I had an installation of Eclipse 4.4 and wanted to move to 4.6. A clean install was the only way, so that's what I did.

I opened my workspace, it built just fine. I wanted to hook it up to the repository, installed Subclipse, but when I try to open the "SVN Repositories" view or any of the other SVN views, I get these:

```
java.lang.Exception
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createErrorPart(ViewReference.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:278)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:316)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:536)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:520)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:70)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.subscribeTopicToBeRendered(PartRenderingEngine.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler.handleEvent(EventObjectSupplier.java:80)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setToBeRendered(UIElementImpl.java:303)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:612)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:581)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:770)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:744)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:677)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1205)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showPart(WorkbenchPage.java:1283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1274)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4316)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4312)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4292)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.openView(ShowViewHandler.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.openOther(ShowViewHandler.java:110)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.execute(ShowViewHandler.java:77)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:286)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:507)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:558)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:378)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:324)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1078)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1126)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1547)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4910)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_CHAR(Tree.java:6079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4791)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:6074)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2552)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3814)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

It happens regardless of the SVN driver I try (SVNKit or JavaHL). Please help.

Looking at the error log, I find this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-10-18 08:12:47.803
!MESSAGE Invalid input     url:platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui/icons/full/eview16/class_hi.gif
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui/icons/full/eview16/class_hi.gif".
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:61)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:209)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.access$1(URLImageDescriptor.java:200)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor$URLImageFileNameProvider.getImagePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:53)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.DPIUtil.validateAndGetImagePathAtZoom(DPIUtil.java:328)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:202)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ViewLabelProvider.getImage(ViewLabelProvider.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider.update(ColumnLabelProvider.java:35)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:118)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:474)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2170)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTreeViewer.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$$Lambda$49/1065997164.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:795)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:766)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalSetExpanded(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2044)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setExpandedElements(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2417)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ShowViewDialog.restoreWidgetValues(ShowViewDialog.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ShowViewDialog.createDialogArea(ShowViewDialog.java:177)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.openOther(ShowViewHandler.java:102)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.execute(ShowViewHandler.java:77)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:286)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:507)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:558)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:378)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:324)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1078)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1126)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1547)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4910)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_CHAR(Tree.java:6079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4791)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:6074)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2552)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3814)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Comment: What was shown earlier in the log?

Answer (score 1):

TODO: File a bug with Eclipse.

But for posterity, here're the steps I took to get it to work again in case someone else runs into it:

- Deleted old Eclipse installation
- Reinstalled Eclipse
- Create HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables.
- Let Eclipse go through an update cycle where it pulled a bunch of old plugins.
- Uninstalled SubClipse.
- Reinstalled SubClipse.

Then it finally loaded with SVN Repositories view available and I was able to hook my project up.